# JQuery Mobile Events + RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I want to use this plugin https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events with RequireJS. I have tried to follow this example https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-shim and I can use JQuery but not the plugin. Can somebody give me an example with the requirejs.config, define with jquery and jquery mobile events plugin and an utility function from the plugin? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
//app.js (requirejs.config)

requirejs.config({
"baseUrl": "js",
"paths": {
  "jquery": "libs/jquery",
  "plugins": "libs/plugins"
},
"shim": {
    "plugins/jquery.mobile_events": ["jquery"]
}
});


requirejs(["example"]);

//example.js (define with utility function)

define(["jquery", "plugins/jquery.mobile_events"], function($){
$(function() {
var tester = $('#tester');
tester.mobile_events().doubletap(function() { console.log('"doubletap" called'); }); //line 4, see output browser log
});
});

//html 

<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Mobile Plugin+ReuireJS</title>
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="tester">Action Area!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, I'm currently using the plugin and jquery loading the scripts in the html (like the example on ben-major jquery-mobile-events) and it works fine but I would like to use it with RequireJS.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Output - Browser Log

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (00:31:49:657 | error, javascript)
    at  (public_html/js/example.js:4:8)
    at f (public_html/js/libs/jquery.js:1:18278)
    at p.add (public_html/js/libs/jquery.js:1:18590)
    at st.fn.st.ready (public_html/js/libs/jquery.js:1:12656)
    at st.fn.st.init (public_html/js/libs/jquery.js:1:12181)
    at st (public_html/js/libs/jquery.js:1:10867)
    at  (public_html/js/example.js:2:5)
    at k.execCb (public_html/js/require.js:28:476)
    at W.check (public_html/js/require.js:18:212)
    at  (public_html/js/require.js:22:249)
    at  (public_html/js/require.js:8:70)
    at  (public_html/js/require.js:23:100)
    at x (public_html/js/require.js:7:172)
    at W.emit (public_html/js/require.js:23:71)
    at W.check (public_html/js/require.js:19:191)
    at W.enable (public_html/js/require.js:22:470)
    at W.init (public_html/js/require.js:16:383)
    at D (public_html/js/require.js:14:20)
    at k.completeLoad (public_html/js/require.js:27:409)
    at k.onScriptLoad (public_html/js/require.js:29:77)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please be specific in your question.

Comment: Anybody can explain me the problem or find a solution?